# Visual Studio 2013 gets stuck on "Preparing solution"

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, solution

After mapping a solution from a Tfs server, Visual Studio 2013 got stuck on the "Preparing solution" dialog after opening a solution. The IDE is still responsive but unusable due to the preparing solution dialog. I haven't had this happen before for the previous mapped solutions.
I read about deleting solutionname.sln.docstates.suo file but I couldn't find it in my workspace yet

Comment: How long did you wait? How many times have you closed and re-opened Visual Studio? Have you tried restarting your machine?

Comment: after mapping the solution I re-opened VS, and I had the same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i would try two things
- can you move Preparing window? Is it possible there is a prompt window hidden under it? There was similar issue with sourcesafe and vs2010
- delete whole directory and download all files again, or even create new workspace

Hope this helps!